# Typescript workflow in 2016

Tags: typescript, workflow, webstorm, typescript1.8

I'm a complete newbie to web development. I've been wanting to try to develop a simple, client-side project in Typescript (in this instance, a game, but this question applies to other projects as well). No server technology, just something that runs in a browser.

I booted up Webstorm and managed to get a simple Typescript project up and working in minutes.

However when I attempted to set up some structure and a reasonable workflow for a larger project, I started running into what seems to be an insane amount of tools, managers, build systems, each in various states of depreciation.

I'm after a way to simply and reliably:

- **Use multiple files without manually including script tags**
- **Use external type definitions and javascript libraries and load them in a sensible way**

For my own code, it seems like es6 modules are my best bet, but for some reason it seems like I still need to use a third party module loader? There seems to be a huge variety of them available - commonjs, requirejs, systemjs, webpack. Also, although numerous sources are recommending using es6, it's still not fully supported in the majority of browsers, meaning I need to get transpilation going as well. Also, somewhere along the lines there's a build process using gulp/grunt that I don't even know if I need do use!

I'm not at all sure what to do for external modules. I tried Bower but it still seems like I need to include the  tags manually for all my external libraries (not a *huge* problem but I'm sure there's a better way!)

And that's really the general feeling I'm getting through all of this - surely there's a better way to do things. But wading through the mountains of outdated information means that I haven't been able to find anything solid.

So - front end experts - what would you suggest to a complete newbie as a good workflow for Typescript (or even just Javascript) development in today's world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm after a way to simply and reliably:
>
> - Use multiple files without manually including script tags
> - Use external type definitions and javascript libraries and load them in a sensible way

The easiest way : [just use Webpack](http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/).

For the whole picture, you can choose between: the bundlers [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/). With these solutions, a bundle is re-built with all the JS code after each modification in the code. Or the asynchronous loaders [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) ([here is a tutorial](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/)) with JSPM for bundling, or [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/).

Notice that, with the use of ES6 syntax `import` / `export` in the TypeScript code, the choice of the loader doesn't implies major difference in the TypeScript code. The same code can be compiled to the different formats, with the help of the TS `module` option.

> For my own code, it seems like es6 modules are my best bet, but for some reason it seems like I still need to use a third party module loader?

You're right.

Read [the article from Mozilla](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/):

> **What does `import` actually do?**
>
> Would you believe… nothing? [...]
>
> ES6 leaves the details of module loading entirely [up to the implementation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule).

And there is an unfinished programmatic API. See also [the book of Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://www.2ality.com/2013/07/es6-modules.html):

> **The module loader API is work in progress**
>
> As you can see in [the repository of the JavaScript Loader Standard](https://github.com/whatwg/loader/), the module loader API is still work in progress.

About the necessity of bundling, I suggest [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/bundling-modules-future.html).

But today, with TypeScript and a loader, you'll be able to use easily the standard syntax `import` / `export` on a large front-end project.

...

> Also, although numerous sources are recommending using es6, it's still not fully supported in the majority of browsers, meaning I need to get transpilation going as well.

It's still required to understand the differences in the targeted browsers. But for the new API that can be polyfilled, the [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) can be packed with the code of your application.

Comment: Advising someone to use webpack, which is a bundler, where person actually needs a module loader, i believe, is a bit misleading. 

Its better to utilise UMD like SystemJs than webpack which sole purpose is module bundling as a priority that can/may sometimes hinder AMD lazy-load advantage. It can do unnecessary things one doesn't need.

Sure, you can do something that with webpack, but if bundling is not what you want as a priority, don't.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in your `tsconfig.json` you can specify what you want.

I advise checking SystemJS (and jspm bundling), the learning curve is a bit steep, but it's worth it.

You can then load any kind of module and assure that its being executed correctly.

Angular2 Official tutorial with typescript is made SystemJS way. You still have to transpile, but you don't necessarily have to bundle as one executable script (which is what Webpack or Browserify are meant to do, the former has some options however).

With UMD you can have many bundles, CommonJS and AMD ones, and load them in many places in harmony. I recommend having main dependency as CommonJS and dynamic sections as AMD's. It is insanely performant.

Comment: Thanks Maciej! I looked into jspm but it's not natively supported by Webstorm so I'm not sure how to integrate its transpilation with Webstorm's transpilation that takes effect on save. I'm not sure what you mean by 'main dependency' and 'dynamic sections' and I don't understand why I have to choose between CommonJS and AMD. I understand that one is asynchronous and one isn't, but aren't they both deprecated in favour of es6 modules? Also, could you provide a link or example on what you mean by 'in your tsconfig.json you can specify what you want'?

Comment: You can load any kind of module using UMD. Funnily enough, webpack doesn't really understand ES6 for instance (as they write in their docs).

ES6 was basically meant to bring a new import standard and unify AMD/CommonJS under this roof. But since you need to bundle for production into one file, because browsers cannot understand (yet), how to make proper ES6 imports from filesystem, so you bundle them up and lose on flexibility (loading separate scripts dynamically for instance, as you've bundled it all).

SystemJS follows on future browser multiplexing and ability to make proper es6 imports.

Comment: In tsconfig you can have system, commonjs or amd under "module". this is what i meant. This is for modules.

Webpack and Browserify bundle them up. JSPM can bundle as well, but in separate bundles with different dependencies, that you can load async/dynamically via SystemJS. Cool stuff isn't it?

Comment: @Daniel: In other words, in your code, you should use the ES6 syntax with `import` / `export` instead of the syntax CommonJS or AMD. But a syntax CommonJS, AMD or UMD is not deprecated in the generated JS code (in 2016).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend my project [Zwitterion](https://github.com/lastmjs/zwitterion). It's new, but it's extremely simple. It is just a server that will handle all of the transpilation for you without any setup on your part. Just include TypeScript files directly in the browser, and you get ES module, async/await, and any other TypeScript feature support automatically. It doesn't support transpilation of plain JS files yet, but that will probably come. So, if you have a TypeScript project, I believe this is the absolute simplest way to get started. And you can build for production if you build your app so that it can be served as a static asset from a CDN. Read [the article](https://hackernoon.com/zwitterion-transpilation-made-simple-a9baa407b006) for more information.